# How to use softmax activation function at the output layer, but relus in the middle layers in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, softmax, activation-function

I have a neural net of 3 hidden layers (so I have 5 layers in total). I want to use **Rectified Linear Units** at each of the hidden layers, but at the outermost layer I want to apply **Softmax** on the logits. I want to use the [`DNNClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier). I have read the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier) of the TensorFlow where for setting value of the parameter `activation_fn` they say:

> activation_fn: Activation function applied to each layer. If None, will use tf.nn.relu.

I know I can always write my own model and use any arbitrary combination of the activation functions. But as the `DNNClassifier` is more concrete, I want to resort to that. So far I have:

```
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
  feature_columns=features_columns,
  hidden_units=[10,20,10],
  n_classes=3
  # , activation_fn:::: I want something like below
  # activation_fn = [relu,relu,relu,softmax]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, but this is not possible using only one DNNClassifier. 
As you show in your example, you can supply an activation_fn

> Activation function applied to each layer. If None, will use tf.nn.relu.

But not a seperate one for each layer. To solve your problem, you have to chain this classifier to another layer that does have the tanh actication function.

Comment: Then, how do I chain the classifier to a separate layer? Won't this be equaling to chaining to another classifier? How would be the errors backpropagated then?