# Tensorflow Auto Tagging

Tags: image, image-processing, tensorflow, tagging

I want to know how to make an auto-tagging for images.

I have tried using Tensorflow and pre-trained the models several times. For start, it was quite good for classification.

But now, I need to do auto-tagging.

Using tensorflow the prediction sum result will be always 1.

For example something like this :

> xxx.jpg prediction result :
>
> - Cat  = 0.822
> - Dog  = 0.177
> - Deer = 0.001

The sum will be always 1.

What I wanted is something like this :

> xxx.jpg prediction result :
>
> - Cat  = 0.901
> - Dog  = 0.811
> - Deer = 0.991

Because there might be Cat, Dog and Deer in the same picture in `xxx.jpg`
(just like [Clarifai](https://www.clarifai.com) did.)

I wonder what is the basic concept to achieved that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the last layer you made. As you say the sum of your predictions is always one, this sounds like you applied softmax (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function). 
If you remove this, you get activations for every object.

Please let me know if this helped you!

Comment: Actually, I used the tutorial in here https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/image_retraining/. So, I have not made my own code for the training. Maybe, it's time to do that now. I'll try it out and see if your answer is really working ! Thank you !

Comment: Hi again ! I already try to read & decided to edit the retrain.py from the tutorial link I mentioned earlier. Since It is simplified things a lot for me. I tried to erase the softmax layer, which defined in this line from the retrain.py :`final_tensor = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name=final_tensor_name)`. But, If I just erased it, it won't work because it's missing the final_tensor_name later. So, I just change it to this `final_tensor = tf.nn.relu(logits, name=final_tensor_name)`. But the result is, the value now can get past 1. For example : cat = 1.345 - dog = 0.234543 - deer = 0.

Comment: Anyway, I used relu instead after reading from this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697341/how-to-use-softmax-activation-function-at-the-output-layer-but-relus-in-the-mid]

Comment: So, the solution was to change the Softmax layer to Sigmoid Layer, not just remove it.